# Capture url params and pass to a div

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass a parameter from the url of my page into a div? I would like to append the source from the site url to the data-url inside the dive below. I will use the example word 'friends'.

For example: mysite.com?formSource=friends

The div would look like this:

```
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://form.typeform.com/to/123abc?typeform-medium=embed-snippet#source=friends" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I tried with some JS that looks like this:

```
<script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const formSource = urlParams.get("formSource");
</script>
```

However I wasn't sure how to update the param after the hash tag in the div. Very new to this but did do a bit of googling before asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the div element by its class using JS and then update the data attribute:

```js
const formSource = 'friends';
const element = document.querySelector('.typeform-widget');
element.dataset.url = `https://form.typeform.com/to/123abc?typeform-medium=embed-snippet#source=${formSource}`;
```

```html
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://form.typeform.com/to/123abc?typeform-medium=embed-snippet#source=friends" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Note I'm using a const for `formSource` in this example but it can be replaced with your url param retrieval code.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! However unfortunately I don't seem able to get it working. I have left the div without the '#source=friends' and then added your code inside script tags in the header but it doesn't update.
I am very basic at this so apologise if its a simple mistake!

Comment: My mistake - I didn't have my scripts in the right order. Put your code after the iframe loads and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transfer parameters from your page URL to an embedded typeform, you can use the new [Typeform Embed Library](https://github.com/Typeform/embed/tree/main/packages/embed) and its `transitiveSearchParams` option.

You embed code would look something like this and the library will take care of the rest:

```html
<div data-tf-widget="<form-id>" data-tf-transitive-search-params="formSource"></div>
<script src="//embed.typeform.com/next/embed.js"></script>
```